# react router prevent calling unstable_usePrompt if search params changed

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to prevent user from abandoning the page if he has some unsaved changes.
However, react router seems to trigger this prompt if the search params change, even if I am on the same page.

```
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  unstable_usePrompt({
    when: didValuesChange(),
    message:
      "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? You have some unsaved changes!",
  });
```

I need to check if the current url is the same as the next url without the search params and then skip the prompt, but I can't figure out how to do that.

useNavigation hook returns the location property which states: *"This tells you what the next location is going to be."*

However, it is always undefined when I try to navigate to other pages.

[Docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation#navigationlocation)

For example, setting "{activeTab: 9}" (with useSearchParams) params to "/tours/5" triggers the prompt that I am leaving the page. Even if it is the same page. How can I prevent that trigger by comparing the current route without params with the next route? (Or some other way)

React router v6.8.1

```
const notOnSamePage = () => {
 //?
} 
  unstable_usePrompt({
    when: didValuesChange() && notOnSamePage(),
    message:
      "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? You have some unsaved changes!",
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is useBlocker with a custom modal as a component using call backs. I am using react-router-dom 6.10.0.

```
//You can import into any form (I use formik) and use it like this:
<RouteLeavingGuard isBlocking={dirty} />

export const RouteLeavingGuard = ({ isBlocking, navState }) => {
function useCallbackPrompt(when) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = React.useState(false);
    const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = React.useState(null);
    const [confirmedNavigation, setConfirmedNavigation] = React.useState(false);

    const cancelNavigation = React.useCallback(() => {
       setShowPrompt(false);
    }, []);

    const handleBlockedNavigation = React.useCallback(
      (history) => {
       if (!confirmedNavigation && history.nextLocation.pathname !== location.pathname) {
         setShowPrompt(true);
          setLastLocation(history.nextLocation);
          return true;
        }
       return false;
      },
     [confirmedNavigation, location.pathname]
    );

    const confirmNavigation = React.useCallback(() => {
      setShowPrompt(false);
      setConfirmedNavigation(true);
    }, []);

   React.useEffect(() => {
      if (confirmedNavigation && lastLocation) {
        let destination = lastLocation.pathname.replace(URS.baseName, "");
        navigate(destination, { state: location.state });
      }
    }, [confirmedNavigation, lastLocation, location.state, navigate]);

    unstable_useBlocker(handleBlockedNavigation, when);

    return [showPrompt, confirmNavigation, cancelNavigation];
  }

  const [showPrompt, confirmNavigation, cancelNavigation] = useCallbackPrompt(isBlocking);
 //CustomModal simply uses bootstrap modal
 return (
    <CustomModal
      color={"warning"}
      title={"Unsaved Changes"}
      openModal={showPrompt}
      setOpenModal={cancelNavigation}
      footer={() => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => cancelNavigation()}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="warning"
            onClick={() => {
              confirmNavigation();
              cancelNavigation();
            }}
          >
            Ok
         </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      centered
    >
     <p className="mb-0">There are unsaved changes - are you sure you want to leave?</p>
    </CustomModal>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `unstable_useBlocker` hook, to check current and nextLocation before blocking the user

First of all create your function that will be use by the `unstable_useBlocker` hook

```
const blocker = (currentLocation: Location, nextLocation: Location) => {
  if (
    yourCondition &&
    nextLocation.pathname !== currentLocation.pathname.split('?')[0]
  ) {
    const answer = window.confirm(
      'Are you sure you want to leave? Current changes will be lost.',
    );
    if (answer) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

An then you just have to provide this function to the `unstable_useBlocker` hook

```
unstable_useBlocker((history) =>
  blocker(history.currentLocation, history.nextLocation),
);
```